# How do I create gold data for TextCategorizer training?

Tags: spacy

I want to train a TextCategorizer model with the following `(text, label)` pairs.

Label *COLOR*:

- The door is brown.
- The barn is red.
- The flower is yellow.

Label *ANIMAL*:

- The horse is running.
- The fish is jumping.
- The chicken is asleep.

I am copying the example code in the [documentation for TextCategorizer](https://spacy.io/api/textcategorizer).

```
textcat = TextCategorizer(nlp.vocab)
losses = {}
optimizer = nlp.begin_training()
textcat.update([doc1, doc2], [gold1, gold2], losses=losses, sgd=optimizer)
```

The doc variables will presumably be just `nlp("The door is brown.")` and so on. What should be in `gold1` and `gold2`? I'm guessing they should be [GoldParse](https://spacy.io/api/goldparse) objects, but I don't see how you represent text categorization information in those.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to this example [train_textcat.py](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/master/examples/training/train_textcat.py) it should be something like `{'cats': {'ANIMAL': 0, 'COLOR': 1}}` if you want to train a multi-label model. Also, if you have only two classes, you can simply use `{'cats': {'ANIMAL': 1}}` for label *ANIMAL* and `{'cats': {'ANIMAL': 0}}` for label *COLOR*.

You can use the following minimal working example for a one category text classification;

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load('en')

train_data = [
    (u"That was very bad", {"cats": {"POSITIVE": 0}}),
    (u"it is so bad", {"cats": {"POSITIVE": 0}}),
    (u"so terrible", {"cats": {"POSITIVE": 0}}),
    (u"I like it", {"cats": {"POSITIVE": 1}}),
    (u"It is very good.", {"cats": {"POSITIVE": 1}}),
    (u"That was great!", {"cats": {"POSITIVE": 1}}),
]


textcat = nlp.create_pipe('textcat')
nlp.add_pipe(textcat, last=True)
textcat.add_label('POSITIVE')
optimizer = nlp.begin_training()
for itn in range(100):
    for doc, gold in train_data:
        nlp.update([doc], [gold], sgd=optimizer)

doc = nlp(u'It is good.')
print(doc.cats)
```