# Formatting Training Data for Spacy Text Classification

Tags: json, nlp, spacy

I have been using fasttext for a personal project (for text classification) and have training data formatted as:

*label* [text....]

This is on each line for my existing training data. As a disclaimer, I am relatively new to NLP and training data formats. I was wondering if anyone could offer advice on how to properly format my existing training data to be used in spacy text categorizer. I understand from reading their documentation that the data format accepted is JSON format. Is it possible that the GoldParse tool intended to be used for this task?

edit: found some help on this topic here:  [How do I create gold data for TextCategorizer training?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48834832/how-do-i-create-gold-data-for-textcategorizer-training?noredirect=1&lq=1)